# Is LlamaIndex.ts as rich as LlamaIndex for python?

Tags: node.js, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index, retrieval-augmented-generation

I am building an application which involves uploading some PDF and storing it in Qdrant vector database. Later we can run queries against the PDF and the query response will be powered by a custom LLM. I have to use either [GTE embeddings](https://huggingface.co/thenlper/gte-large) or [MiniLM embeddings](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2).
The problem is I don't see QdrantVectorStore in LlamaIndex.ts which is present in LlamaIndex python.
Also I am having hard time finding help for LlamaIndex.ts even in their discord server. Their kapa chatbot simply refused to help with js code examples.

On the other hand I see Langchain.js have many resources and a rich documentation.

Is it ideal to switch to Langchain for my use case?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a maintainer on LlamaIndexTS

This last month we have been putting a lot of effort into the LlamaIndexTS package, currently, we implemented the Qdrant Vector Store and have more people to give support on the discord, the kapa bot currently isn't configured to answer typescript questions but we will see what we can do.

Cheers, Emanuel